# Your pool's capacity exceeds your workspace's total vcore quota

Tags: apache-spark, azure-synapse

I work now for almost a year with Azure Synapse and from the beginning also with notebooks running on Spark pools. Only since a few months, I get this error message: 
*Operation on target Load Delta Lake failed: Exception: Failed to create Livy session for executing notebook. Error: Your pool's capacity (3200 vcores) exceeds your workspace's total vcore quota (50 vcores). Try reducing the pool capacity or increasing your workspace's vcore quota. HTTP status code: 400.*

What's happening here?

Answer (score 3):

So Microsoft limits the workspace's total vcores at 50. So although you have the possibility to assign up to 200 nodes, you shouldn't assign more than 11 nodes (if you have a small pool). 
11 you might think? That's because a small pool has 4 vcores per node, but there's also always 1 executor overhead that's added to that total.
So, that's another term to add up to the complexity. You have a number of executors available per pool. The formula to calculate the maximum number of vcores is:
*maximum_number_of_vcores = (number_of_executors + 1) * number_of_vcores_consumed_by_each* 
and then the number of executors:
*number_of_executors = executor_per_node * number_of_nodes_configured*

The variables you can play around with, are:

- the pool size (small, medium, large, etc)
- number of nodes
- the number of executors (only on session level).

If you like to increase the number of vcores available for your workspace pools, you can create a service request for that. I would suggest this especially for production environments.

Much of this is knowledge I have from Microsoft support requests, but also combined from logical thinking. So there can be come errors in here.

Comment: Agreed - in Production, 50 turns out to be extremely low. There is a specific category of support ticket for requesting quota increases. Having more won't increase your direct cost, so you can ask for 300 or so without any issues.

Comment: Here is a link that covers the support process need to increase the quota. Hope it is helpful for anyone who stumbles upon this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/535364/syanpse-spark-compute-capacity-exceeded also here is a link to the docs that provides more technical details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-concepts#quotas-and-resource-constraints-in-apache-spark-for-azure-synapse